# Change in momentum for gas particle collision with wall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, momentum, collision

I've attached the question as an image below as it's a graphical question.

It simply states:

"The diagram shows a gas particle about to collide elastically with a wall.

Which diagram shows the correct change in momentum that occurs during the collision?"

The ball, mass **m**, collides with the vertical wall at an angle **θ** to the horizontal, at velocity **v**.

[image: Gas particle collision with wall question]

The answer is B, but I can't quite understand why.

I feel as though using sin/cosine in this question is unnecessary, but I understand the ball initially has horizontal component of velocity **vcosθ** and vertical component **vsinθ**. The collision is elastic, so I believe the ball will bounce off at a trajectory 90° to its initial trajectory, going essentially "north-east".

However I don't understand why, in answer B, one of the momentum directions is south-east. Though, none of the answers really make sense to me, aside from potentially C.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please use homework-exercises tag for such questions in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in momentum is equal to $\vec{p}(final) - \vec{p}(inital) $. In **(C)** final momentum and initial momentum have been added instead of subtracted so it is incorrect. You are also assuming $\theta= 45°$, so the final trajectory will make an angle of $2\theta$ with the inital trajectory (in general) and the "south-east" vector is nothing but $-\vec{p}(inital)$

Comment: Ok, great, I understand this! Thank you :)